# Strange behavior for arrays passed by reference

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I've just got an unexpected result for a simple function which has an argument passed by reference.

Let's presume we have the following arrays:

```
$arr = array(
  'Test' => 1,
  'OtherKey' => 2,
);
$keyTranslation = array(
  'OtherKey' => 'other_key',
  'Test' => 'test',
);
```

*The `$keyTranslation` array might not have the keys defined in the same order as the `$arr`. This is just to explain the need of the function.*

and the following function:

```
function test(&$arr, $keyTranslation) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $arr[$keyTranslation[$key]] = $value;

        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

The unexpected result is when simply call the function having the arrays above as arguments:

```
test($arr, $keyTranslation);
```

**What I was expected?**

```
array(2) {
  ["test"]=>
  int(1)
  ["other_key"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

**What I've got?**

```
NOTICE Undefined index: test on line number 10

NOTICE Undefined index: other_key on line number 10

NOTICE Undefined index: on line number 10
array(0) { }
```

**Why was this happened?**

Because each time I am adding a new value to the passed by reference array, the loop is iterating also over that value and unset it.

**The question**

Is this normal? or it is a bug in PHP?

Comment: Which is line 10? the `unset()`?

Comment: No.. it is `$arr[$keyTranslation[$key]] = $value;`

Comment: You are adding a value of $keyTranslation array to key of $arr. So in the next loop, this key (test, other_key) will be undefined in $keyTranslation as key (there is no 'test' key in $keyTranslation, only value). It is normal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would use as it seems a bit dodgy to be setting & unsetting elements of an array while `foreach`ing through it...

```
function test(&$arr, $keyTranslation) {

    $newarr = array();

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $newarr[$keyTranslation[$key]] = $value;
    }

    $arr = $newarr; // Not sure if you'd have to unset $arr first...
}
```

Comment: @DarkBee Perhaps it technically can be done, but it could cause confusion as shown in Stavros' comment to the OP.

Comment: The default behavior in PHP while foreaching an array is creating a copy of this array in the background

Comment: I will accept your answer because it is not altering the structure keys in the loop. As the PHP documentation says: `As foreach relies on the internal array pointer in PHP 5, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior. In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you test if the translated key exists :

```
<?php

$arr = [ 'Foo' => 1, 'Bar' => 2 , 'dont_change' => 3, ];
$trans = [ 'Foo' => 'bar', 'Bar' => 'foo', 'Foobar' => 'foobar', ];


function test(&$arr, $trans) {
   foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
       if (!isset($trans[$key])) continue;
       $arr[$trans[$key]] = $value;
       unset($arr[$key]);
   }
}

test($arr, $trans);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

No Bug here. First of all the keys in `$arr` are `'Test'` and `'OtherKey'`. In your function you try to access `$arr['test']` and `$arr['other_key']`, which do not exist, hence the notices. Then you unset the key and therefore the result is that `$arr` is null after the function call, as you passed `$arr` by reference.

Comment: Ok.. I understand the undefined index part.. but why the loop is iterating over the new keys and not only over the original ones..

Comment: I think its because of this (from the manual):  As foreach relies on the internal array pointer in PHP 5, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yes @dev0 that's exactly what I wrote as a comment to the accepted answer.. Thank you for support!